# How to avoid using repetetive phrasing in javascript single line 'if' statement

Tags: javascript

I was writing some code and found this annoying, and couldn't find an answer after some research. Although it works fine it feels very clumsy having to write `this.className` three times:

```
this.className != 'selected' ? this.className = 'selected' : this.className = 'unselected';
```

I found out this works..

```
this.className = (this.className != 'selected') ? 'unselected' : 'selected';
```

..however i was wondering if it's possible to achieve the same function but were `this.className` is only written once, something similar to this:

```
this.className = 'selected' ? 'unselected' : 'selected';
```

open to any suggestions.

Comment: Nope, that second code block is as short as it gets, aside from the fact that `()` there ins't necessary.

Comment: First version is bad (because of the repetitivity), second version is good (because this is exactly why ternary exists), third version is really bad (because you should avoid using the result of an affectation as a boolean test, and is hard to understand).

Comment: BTW, the `?:` syntax is generally called [the "ternary" or "conditional" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: first version is bad on multiple levels

Comment: Why not just toggle class?

Comment: what are the possible other values than `'selected'`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Specifically, it's **the** conditional operator, which is **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands). It's currently JavaScript's only ternary operator, but that may not always be true... :-)

Comment: The conditional operator has 3 operands. A ? B : C .   If the first operand is true, it returns the second operand, otherwise the third one

Comment: Not that it's otherwise what you are looking for (it isn't), but the last version also has the common error of using the assignment operator (`=`) rather than the equality comparison operator (`==`).

Comment: @Cerbrus - that will have to do then, thanks <3

Comment: @epascarello - First, I am aware the first one is bad, it was just to show the idea for what i was going for. Secondly, maybe toggle class is better, the reason Im not using it is because I dont know what it is, but I will now research it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...however i was wondering if it's possible to achieve the same function but were this.className is only written once, something similar to this

No, you can't do that, your second option is pretty much it in the general case:

```
this.className = (this.className != 'selected') ? 'unselected' : 'selected';
```

Your third option would result in it *always* setting `'unselected'` because `'selected'` is truthy, so the value of the second operand (`'unselected'`) will always be the result.

---

Of course, getting into the specifics around DOM elements and classes: You could always just have a `selected` class and toggle it (perhaps via `this.classList.toggle('selected')`). Not having the class would be equivalent to having the `unselected` class.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the best option

```
this.className = (this.className != 'selected') ? 'unselected' : 'selected';
```

Third is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you could always write a method to do it

```js
function switchProperty(obj, prop, test, flip){
  obj[prop] = obj[prop] == test ? flip : test;
}

var myObj = {
   foo:"bar"
}

console.log(myObj.foo);
switchProperty(myObj,'foo', 'bar', 'baz');
console.log(myObj.foo);
switchProperty(myObj,'foo', 'bar', 'baz');
console.log(myObj.foo);
```

Your usage would be

```
 switchProperty(this,'className','selected','unselected');
```

Comment: I am not using it a lot, but thanks for the tip anyway <3

Answer (score 0):

State and class names are different things imo.

What about a variable which stores the state like:

```
this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
this.className = (this.isSelected ? 'un' : '') + 'selected';
```